# Regular expression mulit replace. Replace Mmm->dd

Tags: regex, replace, expression

Is it possible to replace with multi patterns.

String: (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)

Replace: string: (01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)

For example:

```
String: 05 Jan 2013 -> 05 01 2013

String: 20 Nov 2012 -> 05 11 2012
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: What is the programming language you're using ?

Comment: also please notice that such an easy query doesn't require Regex

Comment: I have no idea what the programming language is.

My original text string looks like sow: Wed, 19 Dec 2012 14:49:08 +0000

Then I've useed: 
   
  clear_regex="/Mon, |Tue, |Wed, |Thu, |Fri, |Sat, |Sun, | ..:..:..| .?0000/"

Output string now looks like: "19 Dec 2012"   And I need it to be "19 12 2012"

And when I use: 

replace_regex="/Dec/" replace_with="12" , BUT i need the replace to include all of the patterns "Jan, Feb....,Dec" and that I just can't figure out.

My head is spinning

Comment: What is the technology or programming language you are using Regex in?
(e.g C++/JAVA/PHP/Python/Perl/Javascript........etc)

Comment: It's used in a wordpress shortcode, so PHP

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible - at least not in the way you've described, and not in any regular expression engine I've ever used. The closest you could get for a succinct approximation of the effect you seek is to chain the replacements. In JavaScript for example:

```
var newString = '05 Jan 2013'.replace(/Jan/i, '01').replace(/Feb/i, '02').replace(/Mar/i, '03').replace(/Apr/i, '01'); //And so on
```